# Combine lists while overriding values with same name in R

Tags: r

I have two lists with named elements:

```
a <- list(a=1, b=2)
b <- list(b=3, c=4)
```

I want to combine these lists, so that any elements in a that have the same names will be overwritten by the list b, so I get this out:

```
list(a=1, b=3, c=4)
```

I know I could do this in a loop, but is there a more compact way of doing this in R?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

R has a built in function to do that `modifyList`

```
modifyList(a, b)
```

Comment: Base R has a lot of goodies. Try `help(package = "base")` every time you start R and learn 5 functions :-)

Comment: `modifyList`, wow. Had no idea this function existed. Plus your comment on `help(package = "base")` deserves an additional +1 (shame can't be).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple solution:

```
# create new list
newlist <- c(a,b)

# remove list element(s)
newlist[!duplicated(names(newlist), fromLast = TRUE)]
```

The result:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 4
```

---

An even simpler solution with `setdiff`:

```
c(a[setdiff(names(a), names(b))], b)

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 4
```