# Generate a vector of functions

Tags: r, function, vector

I have a function of a single variable, and various parameters.

For each value of one of the parameters (the others are fixed) there is a single root of the function.  From a vector of the parameter I would like to generate a vector of the roots (using `uniroot`).

The actual example I'm working on is a bit messy, but I'll give it.  Here are the fixed parameters:

> ```
> eta_inf = -0.0139
> eta_0 = 178.5
> lambda = 2.4954
> m = 0.83094
> ```

Here is the function:

```
crossFnc <- function(gamma_dot) tau - gamma_dot*(eta_inf + (eta_0-eta_inf)/(1 + (lambda*gamma_dot)^m))
```

Here is an example of a root for a particular value of the `tau` parameter:

> ```
> tau=10
> uniroot(crossFnc, c(0,1))$root
> ```
>
> [1] 0.06900807

I would like to generate a vector of these roots, for example, for:

```
tau <- seq(0,10,length.out=101)
```

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: What language is this? Root is a bad label (as it's meant to represent the Unix super user).

Comment: Does the answer in this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508519/how-to-add-elements-to-a-list-in-r-loop

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a `for` loop:

```
my.roots <- vector()
tau.seq <- seq(0,10,length.out=101)
for (i in seq_along(tau.seq)) {
  tau <- tau.seq[i]
  my.roots[i] <- uniroot(crossFnc, c(0,1))$root
}
#> head(my.roots)
#[1] 0.000000000 0.000566379 0.001142346 0.001726677 0.002257765 0.002848007
```

Comment: Was trying to avoid a loop.  Answer was simple.  See above.  Thanks.

Comment: @SteveK What's wrong with loops? `sapply` just hides the loop from you.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `sapply`:

```
# Notice the second argument
crossFnc <- function(gamma_dot, tau) { 
    tau - gamma_dot*(eta_inf + (eta_0-eta_inf)/(1 + (lambda*gamma_dot)^m))
}

# I only use length.out = 10
tau <- seq(0,10,length.out=10)

# Apply function(x) to every value in tau
myRoots <- sapply(tau, function(x) {
  uniroot(crossFnc, c(0,1), tau=x)$root 
})

myRoots

>[1] 0.000000000 0.006433349 0.013166577 0.020236503 0.027594321 0.035253401 0.043217816 0.051493442 0.060087456
>[10] 0.069008069
```

Comment: Works!  

crossFnc2 <- function(gamma_dot, tau) tau - gamma_dot*(eta_inf + (eta_0-eta_inf)/(1 + (lambda*gamma_dot)^m))

 sapply(tau, function(x) {
+     uniroot(crossFnc2, c(0,1), tau=x)$root 
+ })
  [1] 0.000000000 0.000566379 0.001142346 0.001726677 0.002257765 0.002848007
  [7] 0.003427169 0.004009318 0.004594418 0.005182443 0.005773373 0.006367191

etc.  Thanks!