# R: add elements to list in a loop in a tryCatch

Tags: r, list, loops, try-catch

I'm trying to parse JSON contained in a dataframe column, some of which is corrupted. As a first step I want to identify the corrupted rows, and use that to subset the dataframe.

I'm using the trick from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508519/how-to-add-elements-to-a-list-in-r-loop) using `c()` to populate the list (even though I know it's slow):

```
myRows <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(myDataframe)) {
  tryCatch({myDataframe$myJSONstring[i] %>%
    fromJSON() %>%
    length()},
    error = function(e) {print(i); myRows <- c(myRows, i)})
}
```

However, this doesn't work. `print(i)` works fine, but after running the loop `myRows` is still just an empty list. Is there some restriction on what code can run in the error bit of a tryCatch?

Comment: This is a scoping issue (you do the assignment in the local scope of the function). You probably could do `myRows <<- c(myRows, i)` but I'm not sure without testing it. Scoping within `tryCatch` is a bit complicated. Preferably you should redesign the whole approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little example of how you could solve your issue: (everyone seems to cry about `<<-`. Somehow assigning to global scope or global vars seems to be bad practice.)

```
env = environment()
env$ans <- rep("works",10)

vec <- rep(1:0,each = 5)

for (i in seq_along(vec)) {
    tryCatch({ if(vec[i]) stop("error message") else {"success"} },
            error = function(e) {print(i); env$ans[i] <- "error"})
}
```

---

```
#> env$ans
# [1] "error" "error" "error" "error" "error" "works" "works" "works" "works" "works"
```

So somehow if you call the property of the environment `env` you can access it from inside tryCatch.

Answer (score 5):

Though there already is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155401/r-add-elements-to-list-in-a-loop-in-a-trycatch/53155760#53155760), I will post another way, without creating an environment.
If the result of `tryCatch` is assigned to a variable, it can be tested later. The trick is to return the error in the error function.
Example based on the accepted answer, same errors.

```
vec <- rep(1:0, each = 5)

ans <- lapply(seq_along(vec), function(i) {
  tryCatch({ if(vec[i]) stop("error message") else "success" },
           error = function(e) e)
})

bad <- sapply(ans, inherits, "error")
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```