# Ways to optimise a nested for loop involving list appendage?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, purrr

I am extracting data for specific geographical areas and specific indicators from the public health agency in the UK using a package they developed for pulling data from their API called `fingertipsR`, and then inserting them in to an empty list, where the list consists of lists (geographies) which contain lists representing each indicator.

```
geog <- c("E38000220", "E38000046", "E38000144", "E38000191", "E38000210", 
"E38000038", "E38000164", "E38000195", "E38000078", "E38000139", 
"E38000166", "E38000211", "E38000147", "E38000183", "E38000028", 
"E38000053", "E38000126", "E38000153", "E38000173", "E38000175"
)
indicators <- c(241, 92588, 90672, 90692, 90697, 90698, 90701, 90702, 91238, 
90690, 90694, 93245, 93246, 93244, 93247, 93248, 93049, 93047, 
90700)

## install.packages("fingertipsR"); library(fingertipsR)
library(dplyr)

list <- list()

start <- Sys.time()
for (geog_group in geog) {
    for (indicator_number in indicators) {
    list[[geog_group]][[as.character(indicator_number)]] <- fingertips_data(IndicatorID = indicator_number, AreaTypeID = c(152, 153, 154)) %>% 
      filter(AreaCode == geog_group, TimeperiodSortable == max(TimeperiodSortable)) %>% 
      select(Timeperiod, Value) %>% distinct()
  }
}
end <- Sys.time()
end-start
```

On my work laptop, this takes around 15 minutes to execute - I'm wondering if there are any easy ways to optimise this code - possibly with `lapply` or `purrr`?

Edit: Ideally I want the indicators for each geographical area to be in one data frame, as they all share the same columns `Time period` and `Value` - I was going to deal with that after `unlist()` or something similar - but if anyone has ways to solve that inside the for loop I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You can pre-allocate your list, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26509347/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more condensed loop (taking roughly 25 sec.)

```
result_list <- list(length(indicators))
for (k in seq_along(indicators)) {
  ind   <- indicators[k]
  # load the data once per indicator
  tmpDF <- fingertips_data(IndicatorID = ind, AreaTypeID = 152:154)
  # retrieve the rows corresp. to max per geog
  out <- t(vapply(seq_along(geog), function (s) {
    row_geog <- which(.subset2(tmpDF, which(names(tmpDF) == 'AreaCode')) == geog[s])
    row_max <- which.max(.subset2(tmpDF, which(names(tmpDF) == 'TimeperiodSortable'))[row_geog])
    res <- tmpDF[row_geog,c("Timeperiod","Value")][row_max,]
    res <- c(Timeperiod = res$Timeperiod, Value = res$Value)
    if (length(res) == 0) res <- c(Timeperiod = NA_character_, Value = NA_character_)
    return (res)
  }, character(2)))
  # save result for indicator[k]
  result_list[[k]] <- data.frame(indicator = ind, geog, 
                                 Timeperiod = out[,1], 
                                 Value = as.numeric(out[,2]),
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
}
```

I am not really familiar with `fingertipsR` but it seems to get the job done (correct me if I'm wrong), here is the first element of the result:

```
head(result_list[[1]])
# indicator      geog Timeperiod    Value
# 1       241 E38000220    2017/18 8.214912
# 2       241 E38000046    2017/18 7.907130
# 3       241 E38000144    2017/18 9.139239
# 4       241 E38000191    2017/18 8.891195
# 5       241 E38000210    2017/18 8.311592
# 6       241 E38000038    2017/18 6.653444
```

**Changes**

Here is what I changed from your version:

- I wrote only one `for` loop (strictly speaking, there are still two loops in my version as I am using `vapply`) iterating over the indicators. The main reason wasn't even to have less looping (which in itself already is motivation enough) but to call the function `fingertips_data` as few times as possible: those function calls are very slow and do not depend on `geog`, only the subsetting does.
- So for every `indicator` the function `fingertips_data` is called once and then using `vapply` the subsetting and finding the max is done
- As a result, the output has a slightly different format but essentially it contains the same information

Comment: This is great, thanks. My R skills still have a long way to go before I can write something like this off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm curious about this part: `for (k in seq_along(indicators)) {
  ind   <- indicators[k]...` seems to be same as `for (indicator_number in indicators){..`,  but I'm guessing the former is usually more computationally efficient?

Comment: @VY Force of habits haha In this case yours is actually a little faster and cleaner as well. I used `seq_along` as it often offers better performance, not in this case. I'd probably stick to your version (primarily for readability).